# possible to create watch in stock item with email notification

Tags: python, node.js

I want to create a script in python or javascript where I can check to see if an item is in stock or not. As soon as it gets in stock I want to be emailed so that I know it is in stock. I feel like this is possible for sure but wondering how accurate would can it be and does it require me to pay in order to do this. The reason why I am thinking this is because I believe I would have to make many requests to keep watching the item. I'm not sure of the most efficient way of doing this would be and would like to do it free if possible as I am only doing this for fun.

Comment: You'd need a process running at all times on a host, e.g. public cloud (paid service) or your machine or similar, and scrape the website periodically to see whether the item is in stock.

Comment: Okay, I figured that I would need to pay in order to do this. Thanks for the answer